# Versions table size getting out of control

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paper-trail-gem

```
Rails 3.2
```

I am using the PaperTrails gem to track activities in several models. The problem I'm having, is that the size of the versions table is getting out of control, and it's affecting performance.

Anyone else run into this situation, and if so, do you have any advice?

Comment: Do you need to keep all versions for all time, or is it OK to keep only most recent N versions per record? (https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail#2e-limiting-the-number-of-versions-created)

Comment: I need all versions. Otherwis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> .. the size of the versions table is getting out of control, and it's affecting performance.
>
> > Do you need to keep all versions for all time, or is it OK to keep only most recent N versions per record?
>
> I need all versions

[Keeping fewer versions](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail#2e-limiting-the-number-of-versions-created) is the best solution, but even if you must keep all versions, you have a few options.

1. PT 10 (unreleased) will give you the ability to [drop the `object` column](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail/pull/1122) in your `versions` table. This will save you 50% disk space, but you will not be able to `reify`. Also, support for rails 3 was dropped in PT 6, so you'd have to upgrade rails (you really should, anyway. rails 3 is dead).
2. If you can't drop your `object` column, you can split your `versions` table into multiple tables using [Custom Version Classes](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail#6a-custom-version-classes). However, this technique is not supported by [PT-AT](https://github.com/westonganger/paper_trail-association_tracking) yet.
3. Fine tuning: See docs section: [What is Versioned and When](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail#2-limiting-what-is-versioned-and-when)